# How to permanently redirect JSP with parameters using urlRewriteFilter?

Tags: java, redirect, spring-mvc, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

We are moving old JSP based web application to Spring MVC controller and using **urlRewriteFilter** (http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) for redirects.

We need to permanently redirect old JSP with parameters to controller view:

```
FROM: /products/product-detail.jsp?productId=666
TO: /product-detail?id=666
```

Important thing here is to use `type="permanent-redirect"` as we need the redirect to be SEO friendly.

I have seen many examples and posts of using urlRewriteFilter, all dealing with rewriting of plain JSP without parameters e.g. some.jsp to /newurl

So far only achievement is using forward:

```
<rule>
    <name>Product Detail Old</name>
    <from>^/products/product-detail.jsp(.*)$</from>
    <to type="forward">/product-detail</to>
</rule>
```

But this of course does not rewrite the URL at all:

it results in:    `/products/product-detail.jsp?productId=666`

We have tried also this but it does not work:

```
<rule>
    <from>/products/product-detail.jsp?(.+)</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect">/product-detail?$1</to>
</rule>
```

it results in `/product-detail?p`

Has anyone could help to construct a rule which will satisfy the above criteria using
urlRewriteFilter?

Help most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the following work?

```
<rule>
    <from>/products/product-detail.jsp\?productId=([0-9])</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect">/product-detail?id=$1</to>
</rule>
```

**EDIT**

Sorry. Forgot the slash above in front of the question mark, which is a reserved character within the regex, unless you escape it.

This caught me out yesterday actually, mainly down to copying directly from an old mod_rewrite rule we had in place.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It is correct just need one extra setting to make it happen - see my post bellow.

Answer (score 2):

It does not rewrite on its own... as I have found in manual the `<from>` is using only the URL string without the query string. 
To be able to use query string we need to add `<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">` After this it works like a charm! 
So the final rule:

```
<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">

<!-- more rules here if needed.... -->
<rule>
    <from>^/products/product-detail.jsp\?productId=([0-9])$</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect">/product-detail?id=$1</to>
</rule>

</urlrewrite>
```

Comment: Nice. That might explain one my own issues. Will check it out after the weekend! Could you post a url to that entry in the manual? Cheers

Comment: Fantastic skills there @Lewdmole... Think I should have perhaps RTFM  myself with that one, but glad we both got to our own answers! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways of dealing with this. You can use

```
<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">
```

although this will affect ALL of the rules in your file. To target the query string for a specific rule, use a condition element

```
<condition type="query-string">productId=([0-9])</condition>
```

You can then reference the query string like so

```
<to type="permanent-redirect">/someUrl?%{query-string}</to>
```

Although in your case, you're looking to change the query string so you might want to reference the captured regex

```
<to type="permanent-redirect">/product-detail?id=$1</to>
```